# with each subsequent column the images scale up

Tags: tables, graphics

I'm trying to create a table with 5 columns and 2 rows. The first row should shows images and the second row shows the according text. In my main tex-file I have following code to import the table `\input{chapter3/buttonTable}`. My `buttonTable.tex` File has following code in it:

```
\begin{table}[b]
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ |X|X|X|X|X| }
    \hline
    \includegraphics{./images/buttons/Windows-Buttons.png}
    & 
    \includegraphics{./images/buttons/MacOSX-Buttons.png}
    & 
    \includegraphics{./images/buttons/Gnome-Buttons.png}
    & 
    \includegraphics{./images/buttons/iOS-Buttons.png}
    & 
    \includegraphics{./images/buttons/Android-Buttons.png}
    \\ \hline
    Windows 7 & Mac OS X & Gnome & iOS & Android \\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
```

This is the output:
[image: http://i47.tinypic.com/1z5r8ys.jpg]

Basically I have two questions:

1. Why do the images get bigger and bigger and how can I avoid it?
2. How can I center the text in the table?

Comment: you can avoid it by using the parameter width and height of includegraphics includegraphics[width=2cm,height=1cm,keepaspectratio]{...}

Comment: just a guess: the size of the images are different(!) and includegraphics is not changing them.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately your suggested solution does not work. I have added `includegraphics[width=2cm,height=1cm,keepaspectratio]` to every image but they still scale up.

Comment: The images are nearly the same size (between 75x50 and 99 x 71 pixels)

Comment: As susius said try the width argument, but I'd say don't use `cm` instead make it dependend from your tablewidth, so for example try: `\includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth]{<name>}` or you could also try to scale the images. (e.g. [scale=0.5])

Comment: Do you need tabularx? Have you tried tabular instead?

Comment: Stupid error. I forgot to close the PDF, hence pdfTex could not overwrite the PDF. Long story short @susisstrolch's solution worked. Thank you very much!

What is the best way to center the items in the table and furthermore: what is the best way to scale images down, if they are too big but do not scale them up if they are too small (avoid pixelated pictures)?

Comment: And to centre your columns I would use the array package and define a new command so that I can specify the size of my column too. \usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}} and for the table: \begin{tabularx}{|\linewidth}{\C{0.2\textwidth}|\C{0.2\textwidth}|} ...

Answer (score 1):

I set up a demo and was unable to recreate the problem.
Start with this minimal example and expand it until your problem starts to show.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    \includegraphics[height=1cm]{./images/buttons/splash.png}
    & 
    \includegraphics[height=1cm]{./images/buttons/splash.png}
    & 
    \includegraphics[height=1cm]{./images/buttons/splash.png}
    & 
    \includegraphics[height=1cm]{./images/buttons/splash.png}
    & 
    \includegraphics[height=1cm]{./images/buttons/splash.png}
    \\ \hline
    Windows 7 & Mac OS X & Gnome & iOS & Android \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{tablecaption}
\label{tablelabel}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Johannes. The limiting of the height does work. Previous user also have suggested this workaround. 

PS: I am going to have multiple tables just like the one I posted. How can I make sure, that the columns are all having the same width? Furthermore I want the table to have the same width as \textwidth.

PPS: Is an image scaled up if it is smaller than 1cm or is this the maximum height?